# how to make query on three relation with max number?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I have 3 model

1.SellInvoice Model:

```
protected $table = "sell_invoices";

public function jewelsItems(){
  return $this->hasMany(JewelsItem::class,'buy_invoice_id');
}
```

2.Jewel model:

```
protected $table = 'jewel';

public function jewelsItems(){
return $this->hasMany('App\Models\JewelsItem');
}
```

3.JewelsItem model:

```
protected $table = 'jewel_items';

public function jewel(){
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Jewel');
}

public function sellInvoice(){
    return $this->belongsTo(SellInvoice::class,'sell_invoice_id');
}
```

**Query:** find 10 number of most sale jewel in my db or sort result on number of sales from a date .

**note:** I have a InvoiceDate in SellInvoice and must use it for know which jewel most sale from a date

**try**: i try this for get gruop by on sale's item which sale from date like 2021-03-1:

```
JewelsItem::whereHas('sellInvoice',function ( $query) {
        $query->where('InvoiceDate','>=','2021-03-1');
    })->groupby('jewel_id')->get();
```

but it got me error :

> Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'laravel_goldshop.jewel_items.id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select * from `jewel_items` where exists (select * from `sell_invoices` where `jewel_items`.`sell_invoice_id` = `sell_invoices`.`id` and `InvoiceDate` >= 2021-03-1) group by `jewel_id`)

Comment: Please share your code what you tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try this code and work for me.

```
$jewel = Jewel::whereHas('jewelsItems', function (Builder $query) {
        $query->whereNull('sell_invoice_id');
    })->withCount(['jewelsItems'=> function (Builder $query) use ($date) {
        $query->whereIn('sell_invoice_id',SellInvoice::select('id')->where('InvoiceDate','>=',$date));
    }])->orderBy('jewels_items_count','desc')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
set global 
sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
```

```
set session sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
```